# how to fix unwanted white space caused due to y-axis animation effect?

Tags: javascript, html, css, gsap

I'm working on a y-axis direction movements animation, where changing the y-axis of the sections on scroll to achieve an upward-moving animation effect is leaving a summed-up unwanted white-space/gap between the last section and the footer, is there a way to eliminate the gap? or is there a better approach to this?

I've looked through a lot but can't find a solution to this, I've tried setting a fixed body height but that just makes sections at the bottom disappear, I also tried to use the same animation effect on the footer just like on the sections, but that leaves a gap at the end too.

```js
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

const tl = gsap.timeline({
    scrollTrigger: { 
        trigger: ".two", 
        start: "-=40%",
        end: "+=40%",
      scrub: 2,
    markers: true,
    }
})

tl.to(".two", {
    y: '-140vh',
})

const tl_two = gsap.timeline({
    scrollTrigger: { 
        trigger: ".three", 
        start: "-=200%",
        end: "+=40%",
      scrub: 2,
    markers: true,
    }
})

tl_two.to(".three", {
    y: '-150vh',
})
```

```css
.one {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: yellow;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.two {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200vh;
  background-color: salmon;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.three {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30vh;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<body style="margin: 0 !important">

  <section class="one">text</section>
  <section class="two">text two</section>
  <section class="three">text three</section>

  <div class="footer">footer</div

</body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.5/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.5/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What do you want it to look like when the user has scrolled as far as they can? Are you wanting the final section to show (at least partially) as well as the footer?

Comment: @AHaworth I want it to show the footer as soon as the last section ends, so the class `.three` section then the footer, without the white space between them